# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I really can't figure out why I have this bug.

First of all the debugger stop at machine code

[image]

The thread also shows nothing. The program stop at no code actually

[image]

So  it has something to do with _dispatch_worker_thread

What is that?

Any way how I can debug this? Should I just rollback?

Comment: This usually occurs when an object has already been released before you want to use it. [This blog](http://www.andrashatvani.com/2011/05/understanding-excbadaccess.html) might help but please show some code too.

Comment: Have you got a breakpoint set on exceptions? Click the breakpoints tab -> Hit the plus button in bottom left -> Click 'Add Exception Breakpoint' -> Hit done with default settings is normally fine. Then run again

Comment: I'll try. FOr some reason it doesn't happen again. Also because I am using ARC I think release and stuff should be taken care off.

Comment: Thanks to @Paul.s.  I've been trouble-shooting this for hours. After reading your comment, I DEACTIVATED all Breakpoints. NOW IT WILL RUN.  So I must have a breakpoint set in the wrong place.

Answer (score 8):

This kind of crash will happen when you are running a (vector)extension which is not supported on your CPU.

For example, in xcode 5 under "project-settings / build-settings / Code Generation, set the 
"Enable Additional Vector extensions" to "AVX2". Build your executable.

Now run it on an:

- Intel Core i5: it's going to crash (wherever the compiler decided to use avx2) with 'exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0'.
- Intel Core i7: it will work.

Comment: Don't have this crash on Intel G620 processor
And it crashing every time with AVPlayer class on Intel Core i5.

Answer (score 7):

`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP)` is the by-product of a `__builtin_trap()` - which is a GCC and clang intrinsic function.  On x86 it we get

```
    0x4dfa2:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
    0x4dfa5:  movl   %edx, 4(%esp)
    0x4dfa9:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
    0x4dfad:  calll  0x110ffa                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x4dfb2:  cmpb   $0, %al
    0x4dfb4:  je     38
 -> 0x4dfba:  ud2    
    0x4dfbc:  movl   -32(%ebp), %eax
```

The instruction `ud2` is the culprit here, and is not handled specially by Xcode.

On ARM we this compiles into `trap` and results in a `trace` break-point in XCode.  Is this a bug in `clang` we have here?

Ultimately in the context of the original question,  I suspect that the library function that is failing has hit a assertion.

Comment: As the this exception was the result of an assertion macro, I fixed problem that was generating it in the first place.  Luckily, I had the source code for the component in question.    
Your first port of call should be to get a full backtrace and work down the call-stack.  If - as was the case with another poster of a similar problem which I saw - it's in an Apple supplied library,  I guess you need to check very thoroughly your use of APIs.

Comment: I've found a crash in UIApplicationMain which breaks on this instruction `ud2` since upgrading to Xcode 12.  The project was fine in xcode 11. Any clues as to what would have changed that would cause this to appear?

Comment: the iOS platform SDK?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was adding an observer for `contentSize` to a `UITextView` in viewDidLoad and was never removing it. Fixed it by adding it in `viewDidAppear` and then removing it in `viewWillDisappear`. 
It was so annoying to find out :(

Add observer in `viewDidAppear`

```
[self.textViewMessage addObserver:self
                           forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))
                              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                              context:nil];
```

Remove observer in `viewWillDisappear`

```
[self.textViewMessage removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))];
```